# Is it possible to use RMI with a round-robin load balancer in a distributed environment?

Tags: java, cloud, load-balancing, rmi, round-robin

RMI is a Java network programming API which use the [JRMP protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/spec/rmiTOC.html). If we analyze packets with Wireshark, it shows that the JRMP protocol requires at least 2 request exchanges before establishing a communication between a client and a server.

More detail: The first request exchange is the negotiation step, the second request exchange is the `lookup()` step, then the other request exchanges are the remote procedure calls (when we use methods from our class which extends [`Remote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/Remote.html)). The first remote procedure call contains serialized class's attribute names, if the same method is called a second time there will be some optimisations (an `integer` id will be used for each attribute name instead of `String`).

Less detail: JRMP is complex, because it requires multiple client/server request exchanges. A protocol like HTTP only requires one.

Consider we are working on the cloud, we have multiple nodes with RMI servers, we also have a round-robin load balancer between the RMI clients and our cloud. RMI client sends a negotiation request and the first node receives it, then the load balancer send the `lookup()` request to the second node... Is it possible to use RMI in a distributed environment?

Comment: Theoretically, but is there a good reason in a situation like this not to use an HTTP or messaging interface?

Comment: Hi, yes there's a good reason: If we want to use a synchronous Service Oriented Architecture (SOA) implementation which is built on binary protocol (and not a plain text protocol like HTTP which cost more CPU for complex datas).

Comment: CPU time for serialization/deserialization is trivially cheap these days. The ease of debugging alone is worth the overhead.

Comment: What is this 'negotiation request' you mention?

Comment: It's the first request exchange between the RMI client and server. If you read the packets, the client sends a request with the following magic bytes : 0x4a 0x52 0x4d 0x49 (it never changes), then the server responds with an ACK 0x4e message.

Comment: That's the RMI version protocol, which is sent once per connection. In any case the `lookup()` must be sent over the same connection, and therefore to the same host. The method call may go via a different connection, as the remote object may be listening on a different port. You would have to have your Registry and all remote objects replicated to all hosts in the round robin. You might be better off using RMI/IIOP and a load-balancing ORB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first request exchange is the negotiation step, the second request exchange is the `lookup()` step

Correct, but this only needs to happen once in the life of the client application, not for every remote method call.

> RMI client sends a negotiation request and the first node receives it, then the load balancer send the `lookup()` request to the second node...

Not possible. Both requests travel over the same TCP connection, *ergo* to the same target host.

> then the other request exchanges are the remote procedure calls (when we use methods from our class which extends `Remote`).

Not necessarily. The requests to the target object could go via a different connection, *ergo* they could include another negotiation step. They can also go to a different host from the first target host, regardless of whether or not there is a load balancer present.

> Is it possible to use RMI in a distributed environment?

You would have to have your Registry and all remote objects replicated to all load-balanced hosts, and if the remote objects have sessional interdepencies you could be in a large spot of bother.

You might be better off using RMI/IIOP and a load-balancing ORB.